# OAuth: HTTP 401 Status when trying to get access token to LinkedIn

Tags: java, oauth, linkedin-api, linkedin-j

Using [linkedin-j](http://code.google.com/p/linkedin-j/), I have the following code in one part of my application

```
LinkedInOAuthService service = LinkedInOAuthServiceFactory.getInstance()
        .createLinkedInOAuthService(consumerKey, consumerSecret);
LinkedInRequestToken requestToken = 
                    service.getOAuthRequestToken(linkedinCallbackURL);
String authUrl = requestToken.getAuthorizationUrl();
```

I redirect to the page pointed by `authUrl` and get to the correct LinkedIn page where I authorize my application. Then, the code which generates the page pointed by `linkedinCallbackURL` will execute this:

```
String verifier = request.getParameter("oauth_verifier");
LinkedInOAuthService oauthService = 
    LinkedInOAuthServiceFactory.getInstance()
                  .createLinkedInOAuthService(consumerKey, consumerSecret);  

LinkedInRequestToken requestToken = oauthService.getOAuthRequestToken();  
LinkedInAccessToken accessToken = oauthService
            .getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken, verifier);
```

Unfortunately, I get this error:

> com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.oauth.LinkedInOAuthServiceException: oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException: Communication with the service provider failed: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/accessToken
>
> Caused by: oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException: Communication with the service provider failed: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/accessToken

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out the problem is that I have to use the same `LinkedInRequestToken` object in both points. To do it, I saved it in the session in the first part:

```
LinkedInRequestToken requestToken = 
            service.getOAuthRequestToken(linkedinCallbackURL);
session.setAttribute("requestToken", requestToken); // <== THE BEEF
String authUrl = requestToken.getAuthorizationUrl();
```

Then I retrieved it from session:

```
LinkedInOAuthService oauthService = LinkedInOAuthServiceFactory.getInstance()
        .createLinkedInOAuthService(consumerKey, consumerSecret);  
// LinkedInRequestToken requestToken = oauthService.getOAuthRequestToken();
LinkedInRequestToken requestToken = 
        (LinkedInRequestToken) session.getAttribute("requestToken")  
LinkedInAccessToken accessToken = oauthService
    .getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken, verifier);
```

*Note: Posting the question and the answer because I searched it A LOT and nobody found this specific problem. Doing it in the spirit of [this question on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/should-i-ask-a-question-i-know-the-answer-to). Also, I did not answer some old questions because this error can happen for a myriad of reasons (it is like `NullPointerException` for LinkedIn API...) and the questions I have found did not have the same causes as far as I've seen.*

Comment: +1. I had a similar problem and your work pointed me in the right direction. In my case, I am using WebAPI so I didn't use a session, but a cookie instead and inadvertently reversed the the secret/value when reading the data back out. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: I got error on `Exception in thread "main" com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.oauth.LinkedInOAuthServiceException: oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException: Communication with the service provider failed: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken` how do i solve this?

Comment: Thank you for your response on your own problem!
I am using Liferay and inside my MVCPortlet class i declared a private field that keeps the token.